# Visual Studio 2017 building a release using SQLite DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2017, system.data.sqlite

Ok created a program in visual studio using an SQLite database, now I want to build a release version of it. So I did but when I run the executable my program isn't able to access the database. The database was automatically placed into the release folder that was created upon build, along with the sqlite data extensions.

The program runs but it just doesn't seem to be able to access or reference the sqlite database.

I assume it to be some pathing issue but I'm still a bit at a lost as within the code for setting the datasource I simply used this...

```
    public void BuildConnectionString()
    {
        // Build connection string
        builder.DataSource = "TestDB.sqlite";   //
        builder.Pooling = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems if I add this |DataDirectory| string it automatically finds the path to the database... So I edited the code as so...

```
public void BuildConnectionString()
{
    // Build connection string
    builder.DataSource = "|DataDirectory|TestDB.sqlite";   //
    builder.Pooling = true;
}
```